# How to use an old version of an app that wants to get updated

Tags: applications, apk

I was using an old version of the eBay app and everything worked fine but now as soon as I open the app, it shows a pop-up telling me to update the app which will not let me use it. Changing the system time will remove the pop-up but the app doesn't have internet connection then.

Is there any possibility to remove the pop-up and use the old version again?

Comment: If you are an experienced Android developer + has some experience with "Smali Code" you could decompile the app with `apktool` remove the date check, rebuild the app and then use it. Of course this only works unless the used API on the eBay servers has changed.

Comment: How exactly do you remove the date check after decompiling the app?

Comment: That depends on how the app developer has developed that check. You can look at the Smali code and also look at the decompiled Java code (by Jadx) and search for the Java date functions that can be used for checking the current date/time. If you have identified the code it is often enough to change an `if-eq` to an `if-neq` or totally remove the if expression to change the code.

Comment: I decompiled the app with apktool, removed the specific code, rebuilt the app, and then signed it. After installing it, I can open the app but then there seems to be actually no internet connection available. Do I need to regard anything or why could there be no internet connection now?

Comment: Why type of internet connection? To generic server on the net or app-specific servers? May be the app performs some sort of self-check or sends a hash to the server which then does not answer anymore. You can modify the app like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57570009/150978) and then sniff it's traffic using a proxy like mitmproxy or Fiddler.

Comment: Even when I don't change any code at all, after rebuilding and signing, there is no internet connection at all.

Comment: Then may be the app is checking it's signature. BTW what do you mean by "no internet connection" does the app does not make any requests (not IP traffic at all) or does the app not receive any response from the server?